# Which integral curves of a field are defined for all times t?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Which integral curves of the field $X=x^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are defined for all 
times t?

I would be very thankful if somebody can help me understand what is the standard approach for such problems.

This is a problem in Lee's book Manifolds and Differential Geometry, Is it implied that The vector field is associated to $\mathbb{R^2}$ or a general two dimensional manifold ? or .... ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is implicitly in $\mathbb R^2$; otherwise, '$x$' and '$y$' don't make sense.

As far as a general approach, there are some theorems that can ensure global flows, but they can be hard to check. In this case, I think we are best off working directly with the given vector field. Write down the condition for the integral curves $\gamma(t)$:

$$
\dot\gamma(t) = X(\gamma(t))
$$
i.e. if $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ then
$$
\dot x(t) = x^2, \\
\dot y(t) = y.
$$

Now, if $x(0) \neq 0$, the solution to the first diff. eqn. (it is separable) is $x(t) = \dfrac{1}{C - t}$ where $C = \dfrac{1}{x(0)}$, which is clearly not defined for all $t$.

On the other hand, if $x(0) = 0$ then $x \equiv 0$. Further, for any $y(0)$, the solution of the second diff. eqn. is $y(t) = y(0)e^t$, which is defined for all $t$. Thus, only the integral curves that cross the $y$-axis are defined for all $t$.